# Open a docx file with Phonegap

Tags: cordova, window.open, inappbrowser

Is possibile to open a local docx file with Phonegap on Android??

I have tried with pdf file and there is no problem but, if i try with docx file, even if the type is 'application/word', the system doesn't open the file

Answer (score 0):

As this thread mentioned, I think it's possible. Using inAppBrowser. Have a look

[Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/hdvD_G8nPus)

Look at this portion

> Paul Cervenka      1/24/13
>
> hi, we're viewing all office documents
>   (doc,docx,xls,xlsx,ppt,pptx) in our cordova app with the inAppBrowser.

And if this doesn't work you can write a plugin to open docx with native code.

Comment: Ok, but same person later says
"
Hi Kurt,

I'm using inAppBrowser in iOS, so I've never tested, if you can view office documents on android with it.

Sorry =/"